# Can ‘event’ and ‘action’ never be the same?

Tags: word-usage

Can ‘event’ and ‘action’ never be the synonym? I found out that they both mean something that happens (although action needs a doer), which makes me think they may be used to mean the same. I think they sometimes mean the same as ‘quality’ and ‘state’ do.

Comment: An action can certainly be an event, but an event isn't always an action; it could be something like a thunderstorm, which happens of its own accord.

Comment: @Kate Bunting You mean thunderstorm is weather state/condition so event can also be state/condition, not action? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/storm

Comment: @Kate Bunting It makes me wonder for example ‘cake’ itself can be an event.

Comment: @Kate Bunting https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(philosophy) “Events are objects in time or instantiations of properties in objects.” Is it related?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is related to philosophy rather than actual usage.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney No I’m talking about actual usage. Just reference is philosophical.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney I just want to know ‘object’ can mean ‘event.’

Comment: I mean that a thunderstorm is a thing that happens, not an action that somebody does.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I’ve been waiting for you, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If X is an *action*, it answers the question "what did someone/something do?" - Actions support concepts such as intent and cause.

If X is an *event*, it answers the question "what happened?" - but does not talk about the cause.  Intent doesn't apply because there's no "doer".

> I think they sometimes mean the same as ‘quality’ and ‘state’ do.

No... *quality* and *state* are attributes of things - e.g. you always mean "quality of X", "state of X".